# Maatwebsite Laravel Excel queued export serialization error

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am using Maatwebsite\Excel to handle data exports in my application.  Some of the exports are pretty big, so I want to queue the exports.  I have followed the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/queued.html), but I get the following error when attempting to export:

```
You cannot serialize or unserialize PDO instances
```

I understand that PDO instances cannot be serialized, I just don't understand why it's telling me that since I am following what is said in the docs.  Here's my code:

Controller

```php
$path = 'public/validations/' . $filename;
//the $client var is a record retrieved from a model, $input is the result of $request->all()
(new ValidationsExport($client, $input))->queue($path)->chain([
    // the script never reaches here, but $user is from \Auth::user()
    new NotifyUserOfValidationExport($user, $filename),
]);
```

Export

```php
class ValidationsExport implements FromQuery, WithHeadings, WithMapping, WithStrictNullComparison, WithCustomQuerySize, WithEvents, WithColumnFormatting
{
    use Exportable;

    private $client;
    private $input;

    public function __construct($client, $input)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        $this->input = $input;
    }

    public function query()
    {
        // this does return a query builder object, but this is required for FromQuery and is shown in the docs as an example of how to queue an export
        $this->validations = $this->getValidations();

        return $this->validations;
    }

    public function querySize(): int
    {
        $query = ....
        $size = $query->count();
        return $size;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        // this is an array
        return $this->columns;
    }

    public function columnFormats(): array
    {
        return [
            'A' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'B' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT,
            'C' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
        ];
    }

    public function map($row): array
    {
        $mapping = [];
        foreach($row as $key => $value) {
            if(is_bool($value)) {
                if($value) {
                    $mapping[$key] = "Yes";
                } else {
                    $mapping[$key] = "No";
                }
            }else{
                $mapping[$key] = $value;
            }
        }
        return $mapping;
    }

    //.......
}
```

I assume that the problem comes from using `FromQuery`, but I can't use `FromCollection` because I run out of memory since the export is so big.  I need the built in chunking that `FromQuery` uses. Is there a way I can queue an export using `FromQuery`?

Comment: why are you setting `$this->validations` .. do you need to if you are just going to return from that method?

Comment: You are a genius @lagbox.  I was using that in the `querySize` method at one point, but since decided to do a separate query.  Setting `$this->validations` was causing the issue, and now I can see that it makes perfect sense.  Submit an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need to be setting a member variable `$this->validations` to that builder. That is what is ending up trying to be serialized. If you are just going to return it you don't need to store a copy on the class.